# Page not loading on webview in Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, webview

I have an android app that uses webview to render some react app, and the react app contains the following piece of code that makes the webview not able to render the react app:

```
document.getElementById('content').style.fontSize = newSize + "em";
```

If I remove this line of code the webview is able to render the react app.

Thou when opening from my localhost it does not crash! Something really weird going on.

I use the above code to increase the text size of the article!